# Error when using add-gutter in Singularity Grid System

Tags: singularitygs

I'm using breakpoints in Singularity, and also using the Breakpoint extension for elements outside the grid (a full-width header nav). In my screen.scss file I have:

```
@import "singularitygs";
@import "breakpoint";
@import "base";

$tabletwidth: 40em;
$smalldesktopwidth: 60em;

$grids: 4;
$grids: add-grid(9 at $tabletwidth);
$grids: add-grid(12 at $smalldesktopwidth);

$gutters: 1/3;
$gutters: add-gutter(1/2 at $tabletwidth);
$gutters: add-gutter(1/2 at $smalldesktopwidth);
```

Without the add-gutter() calls it runs fine, but when I add them it breaks with:

```
Syntax error: Undefined operation: "0.5 times 2". 
on line 20 of /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/singularitygs-1.0.4/stylesheets/singularitygs/math/_columns.scss, in `output-isolation' 
from line 7 of /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/singularitygs-1.0.4/stylesheets/singularitygs/_api.scss, in `grid-span' 
from line 102 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/modernlink/sass/screen.scss, in `@content' 
from line 178 of /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/breakpoint-1.3/stylesheets/_breakpoint.scss, in `breakpoint' 
from line 99 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/modernlink/sass/screen.scss
```

Am I using this wrongly? Can anyone offer a suggestion to fix?

Edit: Line 99 of screen.scss is:

```
@include breakpoint($tabletwidth) {
```

Comment: So this turned out to be not a Singularity issue: https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/issues/94

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in Singularity. It'd be great if you could file an issue [over on the issue queue](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/issues?state=open) for us to be able to track. Thanks!

**EDIT:** I am unable to reproduce this error using Singularity 1.0.7 (current version). Please make sure you are at the latest version of Singularity.

Comment: Thanks — I'm moving this to the issue queue. And yes, I'm using 1.0.7.